# Need software to create/run macro to automatically reconnect to the internet

Tags: macros, automation, internet-connection, reconnect

I'm looking for software that will allow me to write a macro/script to get EasyTether to re-connect my Android O/S phone (Ally) to the internet (desktop PC) when the connection gets dropped. The problem is that EasyTether constantly drops the connection. (Every few minutes - a bit random.)  I have checked the forums and many, many people have been having the same problem for a long time.

I want the macro/script to check the internet connection every few seconds, and if there's no connection then do a I right click on the EasyTether status bar icon, and select "connect."

I will write the script.  I'm looking for the software.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with AutoIt. (http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) You can use the "Ping" function (AutoIt) once every few min/sec/whatever and if it returns 0 you run the subroutine to "click" (AutoIt) on the re-connect menu item.

Comment: I will be posting this on some forums the EasyTether people use.  This has been a big problem for a long time.

Comment: I posted this to these forums - very common problem.

http://androidforums.com/evo-4g-support-troubleshooting/133344-easytether-keeps-disconnecting.html#post2843518

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/tech-issues-bug-reports-suggestions/118878-easy-tether-connection-keeps-dropping-please-help.html#post1589371

http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/showthread.php/3640-Easytether-Issues

http://www.droidforums.net/forum/tech-issues-bug-reports-suggestions/106458-my-internet-keeps-disconnecting-when-tethering-plz-help.html#post1589404

Comment: And these: http://www.androidpit.com/en/android/market/apps/app/com.mstream.easytether_polyclef/EasyTether

http://androidforums.com/motorola-droid/176764-easy-tether-easy-tether-lite-users-w-droid.html#post2843626